# Trying to parse a GUID out of a http get in asp webapi

Tags: asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to pass a simple GUID in an http get query string.  What should be a very simple task is not, and I've spent way too much time on this...

The closest I've gotten is the controller method does get hit, but the Guid (i.e. the requestID parm in the controller method below) is empty.
I've tried wrapping the Guid in a class to make it complex, tried stringifying it and passing it as a simple string, tried various URL formats, nothing seems to work.

Here's my Route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Here's my client request:

```
    public async Task<SecurityAnalyticalMeasureResponse> getSecurityAnalyticalOutputAsync(Guid requestID)
    {
        SecurityAnalyticalMeasureResponse r = null;
        try
        {
            //api call...
            string webapiUrl = string.Format("http://{0}/api/Security/Analysis", serverAddress);

            //tell server to accept json formatted messages
            string parameter = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestID, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);


            //make the request (for the response)
            string tmpstr = string.Format("{0}?{1}", webapiUrl, parameter);

            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(tmpstr);

            //wait for the reply
            string responseData = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And Here's my code in the Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Analysis")]
public async Task<SecurityAnalyticalMeasureResponse> getSecurityAnalyticalOutput([FromUri]Guid requestID)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _taskManager.respondSecurityAnalyticalOutput(requestID));
}
```

FWIW I'm able to successfully get guids back in responses from POST messages.

Any help appreciated in advance.

Thanks
David

Comment: How does the request string look like? In other words, what is the content of `tmpstr`?

Comment: Hi Andrei,
tmpstr looks like this:
"http://localhost:56091/api/Security/Analysis?id=a44e3f42-6d04-4cd5-be87-5eb3e28285b3"

I've tried ALOT of variations on the above format

Comment: Then this is the problem. Parameter in url is called `id`, while action method expects `requestID`. Also I recall there were some problems with handling parameters named `id` in MVC, so the best way, i think, is to rename parameter used in request

Comment: Andrei,
You Rock!  That works.
That seems totally non obvious that the literal name in the request sting has to match exactly the var name in the handler.

Very scary that 'rules' like this are not very transparent.

Comment: This is how default model binding works in ASP.NET MVC since the very beginning of this technology. Well, never worked with version 1, but from 2 onwards for sure. You might want to look up a bit about model binding to avoid such problems in future.